# How do I load a widget in an adjacent pane when a toolbutton is clicked?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade, gtk3

I am trying to create a GTK python app for configuring settings and I have been looking at creating a GTK design for the app using Glade.

So far I have created a design with 5 notebooks and it looks somewhat like this:

[image: glade-notebooks]

However, I actually want to use a Gtktoolbar with primary-style toolbar buttons that open the settings in the adjacent pane when the Gtktoolbar buttons are clicked. The current Gtkprimarytoolbar implementation looks like this:

[image: glade-toolbars]

I am very new to Gtk designing and I tried setting the `on_tool_unitysettings_clicked` signal to handle `nb_unitysettings`. I'll admit I don't know what I am doing.

The idea is when I click on the toolbar button, the related notebook gets loaded in the pane below the toolbar buttons. How exactly do I do that? I would be very much happy with a Glade solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up merging both the windows above and changing the notebook's page when each of the toolbar buttons are pressed. I also hid the tabs of the notebook so it doesn't look like there was a notebook there at all.

Here's the python file that handles the signals when the buttons are pressed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler ():
    '''Clicking the toolbars'''
    def on_tool_startpage_toggled(self,nb_mechanig):
        nb_mechanig.set_current_page(0)
    def on_tool_unitysettings_toggled(self,nb_mechanig):
        nb_mechanig.set_current_page(1)
    def on_tool_compizsettings_toggled(self,nb_mechanig):
        nb_mechanig.set_current_page(2)
    def on_tool_themesettings_toggled(self,nb_mechanig):
        nb_mechanig.set_current_page(3)
    def on_tool_desktopsettings_toggled(self,nb_mechanig):
        nb_mechanig.set_current_page(4)


# Basic builder setting up

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("mechanig.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())

# The main Mechanig window that needs to be shown
mechanig_main = builder.get_object('mechanig_main')

# This signal is emitted when you close the window,
# which triggers Gtk.main_quit, which tells the main Gtk loop to quit
mechanig_main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

# This is required, otherwise Gtk leaves the window hidden.
# Useful, like with our dummy "windows" that get reparented
mechanig_main.show_all()

# Runs the main loop
Gtk.main()
```

And the window now looks like this and this is the closest I can get to what I wanted:

[image: Mechanig-glade-previewer]